# Disregard time part when filtering records by date

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My client's database is quite old. For instance old `DATE` columns only contained Date values. But after it has been upgraded, it can now support DateTime values. I have this column called `LAST_UPDATED_DATE` wherein values can vary from `2001-08-16` to `2016-04-28 12:00:12`. The former is inserted into the older version of the database while the later is the upgraded version.

I'm performing search criteria on Grails wherein it needs to retrieve rows on a certain date, for instance, those that were updated last April 25. The question is how? I could do something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date parsedDate = formatter.parse("2016-04-25");

ArrayList records = Table.createCriteria().list {
    ...
    eq("lastUpdatedDate", parsedDate)
    ...
}
```

But not all entries for that day will be selected. The only records will be selected are those which time is `00:00:00`. How can I select all records on that date regardless of their time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for period between midnight of that day and next one:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date parsedDate = formatter.parse("2016-04-25");

ArrayList records = Table.createCriteria().list {
    ...
    ge("lastUpdatedDate", parsedDate)
    lt("lastUpdatedDate", parsedDate + 1)
    ...
}
```